Investigating seasonality and trend in short time series
I am interested in investigating the presence, or lack of, seasonality or trend in very short time series (typically max 12 observations). Case in point: suppose one is looking at average number of goals per match in a football league on a month per month basis (say the aim being to investigate any intraseasonal variation in goal frequency). There are typically 9-10 months per a football league "season". Hence there are only 9-10 data points per season that can be used to infer any pattern. Now one could take look at a pattern from one season to the next to dramatically increase the sample size, but the problem is that players and managers tend to change every season so one season's patterns may not always carry over to the next.
How would one approach  / adapt to this type of series to try to infer any patterns?

With only one period of data available, it is statistically and mathematically impossible to distinguish a seasonal effect from any other trend.

What do you mean by "one period of data"? I can take data for many seasons, if I wanted, but as explained, one season's patterns may not always directly carry over to the next @whuber

Right: that means you don't have any more than one period.  (A "season" would be, say, "summertime," whereas a "period" would be a year-long interval.)  You can't distinguish seasonal changes from other trends with just one period.  A rule of thumb is that you need at least three periods to have any reasonable chance of detecting seasonality.

If you are interested in whether there is a seasonal pattern in the number of goals scored by the average team, you don't particularly care that the composition of these teams changes from season to season. Use as many seasons' worth of data as you have.

Thanks @DoctorMilt
